# Import project spring boot with Gradle get error: Failed to apply plugin 'org.springframework.boot'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I got this error when importing a spring boot project using gradle:

```
The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
A problem occurred configuring root project 'tcvoffice'.
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'tcvoffice'.
Failed to apply plugin 'org.springframework.boot'.
Configuration with name 'runtime' not found.
```

**I'm using Java 11.0.12,   gradleVersion: '4.3', springBootVersion: '1.5.3.RELEASE'**

Can you guys give me a solution so I can solve it?

Many thanks

Comment: Which Gradle version, and which Spring Boot plugin version raises this issue?

Comment: Hi,
 gradleVersion = '4.3' &
 springBootVersion = '1.5.3.RELEASE'
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're multiple issues with your setup from the tooling perspective. According to Gradle's [Java Compatibility Matrix](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html#java), Gradle 4.3 is not compatible to Java 11. Gradle 4.3 supports Java 9 only. The Spring Boot plugin in version `1.5.3.RELEASE` requires Gradle 3.x, according to their [System Requirements](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-system-requirements).

If using Spring Boot `1.5.3.RELEASE` is mandatory, I suggest downgrading to [Gradle 3.5](https://gradle.org/releases/) and Java 8.